# Using NOT IN with GROUP CONCAT in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, group-concat

I'am using the "**GROUP_CONCAT**" function with the "**NOT IN**" statement in my mysql query. But for unknown reason, it doesn't return the correct values:

Here is my query not working:

```
select firstname, lastname
from t_user
where (status_Id NOT IN(Select GROUP_CONCAT(id) from t_status where code = 'ACT'
or code = 'WACT'))

Returns 46 rows
```

Here is my query working:

```
select firstname, lastname
from t_user
where (status_Id NOT IN(1,4))

Returns 397 rows
```

The results of the of the **GROUP_CONCAT** subquery

```
 (Select GROUP_CONCAT(id) from t_status where code = 'ACT' or code = 'WACT') = 1,4.
```

It seems that the query take only care of the first item return by the GROUP_CONCAT subquery.

So I don't understand what's going on and why I do not have the same results in both cases.

Thanks in advance Gael

Answer (score 5):

in this case, you don't need to use `GROUP_CONCAT` function because it returns a string value. AND 
`1, 4` is very different from `1` and `4`.

```
select  firstname, lastname
from    t_user
where   status_Id NOT IN 
        ( Select id 
          from t_status 
          where code = 'ACT' or code = 'WACT'
        )
```

and a better way to right the query is by using `LEFT JOIN`,

```
SELECT  a.firstname, a.lastname
FROM    t_user a
        LEFT JOIN t_status b
            ON a.t_status = b.id AND
                b.code IN ('ACT', 'WACT')
WHERE   b.id IS NULL
```

Comment: 'and a better way'... hm, these days I'm not so sure. NOT EXISTS is PDQ! (Although on a purely aesthetic level, I completely agree)

Comment: @Strawberry that's why I used `better`, didn't say `best` :D

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to exploit the list generated from GROUP_CONCAT as your question asks.  Thus, in general, you can use the list from GROUP_CONCAT as follows:

According to the [specification](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set), you can simply use FIND_IN_SET instead of NOT IN to filter a field by subquery

```
select firstname, lastname
from t_user
where NOT FIND_IN_SET(status_Id, 
    (Select GROUP_CONCAT(id) from t_status where code = 'ACT' or code = 'WACT')
);
```